# insertion sort for pdp-11

Tags: sorting, assembly, pdp-11

I'm studying pdp-11 and assembly, I'm very interested, is it possible to find insertion sort on assembly for pdp-11, thanks in advance for everyone, if yes where?

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is your friend. I assume you already have PDP-11 documentation. And you should at least try to implement it before asking here.